# Maximum Monthly Values whilst retaining the Data at which that values occurred

Tags: python, pandas, time, max

I have daily rainfall data that looks like the following:

```
   Date           Rainfall (mm) 
1922-01-01        0.0 
1922-01-02        0.0 
1922-01-03        0.0
1922-01-04        0.0
1922-01-05        31.5
1922-01-06        0.0
1922-01-07        0.0
1922-01-08        0.0
1922-01-09        0.0
1922-01-10        0.0
1922-01-11        0.0
1922-01-12        9.1
1922-01-13        6.4
```

I am trying to work out the maximum value for each month for each year, and also what date the maximum value occurred on. I have been using the code:

```
rain_data.groupby(pd.Grouper(freq = 'M'))['Rainfall (mm)'].max()
```

This is returning the correct maximum value but returns the end date of each month rather than the date that maximum event occurred on.

1974-11-30   0.0

I have also tried using .idxmax(), but this also just return the end values of each month.

Any suggestions on how I could get the correct date?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`pd.Grouper` seems to change the order within groups for `Datetime`, which breaks the usual trick of `.sort_values` + `.tail`. Instead group on the year and month:

```
df.sort_values('Rainfall (mm)').groupby([df.Date.dt.year, df.Date.dt.month]).tail(1)
```

---

#### Sample Data + Output

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

np.random.seed(123)
df = pd.DataFrame({'Date': pd.date_range('1922-01-01', freq='D', periods=100),
                   'Rainfall (mm)': np.random.randint(1,100,100)})

df.sort_values('Rainfall (mm)').groupby([df.Date.dt.month, df.Date.dt.year]).tail(1)

#         Date  Rainfall (mm)
#82 1922-03-24             92
#35 1922-02-05             98
#2  1922-01-03             99
#90 1922-04-01             99
```

---

The problem with `pd.Grouper` is that it creates a `DatetimeIndex` with an end of the month frequency, which we don't really need and we're using `.apply`. This give you a new index, and is nicely sorted by date though!

```
(df.groupby(pd.Grouper(key='Date', freq='1M'))
     .apply(lambda x: x.loc[x['Rainfall (mm)'].idxmax()])
     .reset_index(drop=True))

#        Date  Rainfall (mm)
#0 1922-01-03             99
#1 1922-02-05             98
#2 1922-03-24             92
#3 1922-04-01             99
```

---

Also can with `.drop_duplicates` using the first 7 characters of the date to get the Year-Month

```
(df.assign(ym = df.Date.astype(str).str[0:7])
   .sort_values('Rainfall (mm)')
   .drop_duplicates('ym', keep='last')
   .drop(columns='ym'))
```